# Is this possible with Subsonic

Tags: c#, database, subsonic, object

I need to generate Entities/Object from selected tables - not all. Is this possible with Subsonic and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the includeTableList and excludeTableList configuration options to specify which tables to generate objects for.

Details of the config options are at: 
http://subsonicproject.com/configuration/config-options/

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to see what effects config-options has is to edit the options in SubStage and "Invoke".

The SubStage executable is in the SubStage-folder of the installation dir. It also helps you with the blocks needed in your web.config-file.